# How to substitute the give formula to $ x = \frac{y+z}{1+yz/m^2}$

Tags: substitution

How to solve for x from$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/m^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2/m^2}} \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2/m^2}}\cdot(1+\dfrac{yz}{m^2}) $$
to
$$ x = \frac{y+z}{1+yz/m^2}$$

There is also a tip, which says
$$\dfrac{x^2}{m^2}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/m^2}}\right)^2-1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/m^2}}\right)^2}$$

Comment: What is your aim?

Comment: It looks like an object is moving to the right in frame $S_1$ with velocity $z$ and frame $S_1$ is moving to the right relative to frame $S_2$ with velocity $y$ and you are trying to find an expression for the Lorentz factor $\gamma=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2/c^2}}$ for the object as seen by frame $S_2$, is that right? If $m=c$ your first expression seems to be equivalent to the second.

Comment: @1.414212 I want to know how the author solved for $x$ from the formula above, so basically the calculation path for that.

Comment: @user5713492 Exactly, that's it, I am looking for the Velocity-addition formula (often called $w$ (or $u$ on Wikipedia)), I wrote with different variables just to  minimalize plagiarism when my work gets checked.

Comment: I would try to substitute $x=m\sin\alpha, y=c\sin\beta, z=c\sin\gamma$ and then simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took both sides to the $-2$ power:
$$1-\frac{x^2}{c^2}=\frac{\left(1-\frac{y^2}{c^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{yz}{c^2}\right)^2}$$
Then took $1$ minus both sides:
$$\begin{align}\frac{x^2}{c^2}&=\frac{\left(1+\frac{yz}{c^2}\right)^2-\left(1-\frac{y^2}{c^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{yz}{c^2}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{1}+\frac{2yz}{c^2}\color{blue}{+\frac{y^2z^2}{c^4}}\color{red}{-1}+\frac{y^2}{c^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\color{blue}{-\frac{y^2z^2}{c^4}}}{\left(1+\frac{yz}{c^2}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\frac{(y+z)^2}{c^2}}{\left(1+\frac{yz}{c^2}\right)^2}\end{align}$$
The terms with corresponding $\color{red}{\text{c}}\color{orange}{\text{o}}\color{yellow}{\text{l}}\color{green}{\text{o}}\color{blue}{\text{r}}\color{violet}{\text{s}}$ canceling. Then multiply by $c^2$ and take square root to get
$$x=\frac{y+z}{1+\frac{yz}{c^2}}$$
Is that what you wanted, or did you rather want to start with the last expression for $x$ and substitute into $\gamma=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you a lot good Sir! And sorry for the mistake with $m=c$, my bad.